# How can I create List<T> with N - 1 equal objects + 1 different one?

Tags: java, list, java-8

I've found `Collections.nCopies` but it returns `ImmutableList` so I can't use `add()`.

What's the most readable way to do it?

Comment: By readable I mean using `Collections.nCopies` instead of plain `for` loop. I want to be memory efficient, too.

Comment: Do you realize this is the same instance in that `List` that is copied `n` times ? It is using an implementation of `List` that basicly takes `n` and the instance to create a "fake" `List`, if you ask for `size()`, return `n`, and any `get(index)` will return the same instance if it is in the correct range. See [Collectinos.nCopies](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.nCopies%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the immutable `List` to `ArrayList` constructor:

```
List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies (n-1, object1));
list.add(object2);
```

or

```
List<YourClass> list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies (n, object1));
list.set(someIndex, object2);
```

In Java 8 you can use `Stream`s:

```
List<YourClass> list = 
    IntStream.range(0,n)
             .mapToObj(i -> i != specialIndex ? object1 : object2)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Well, it looks good, but is it memory efficient (I think we'll create the same list twice basically) to bypass immutability?

Comment: @AlexAlex the original immutable List returned by `Collections.nCopies` takes O(1) memory, so no need to worry about it. In order to have a mutable List, you can't avoid creating a List that takes linear space.

Comment: The second variant is preferable, as by default `new ArrayList<>(collection)` creates an array list with exactly the same capacity as the incoming collection’s size, so adding another element causes a capacity increase operation. So in the second variant, the capacity is perfect right from the start. There is no way to make it significantly faster…